# How do I change Color of Label by getting the Color from another Label?

Tags: c#, winforms, textcolor

I am trying to do something similar to the one in the example but changing the colour of the text/label.

Example:

```
Label1.Text = Label2.Text;
Label2.Text = Label3.Text;
Label3.Text = Label4.Text;
//so and and so forth
```

I am looking for a very  simple solution like the one shown in the example but with colors.
I am using `Windows Form App` with `.Net Framework 4.7.2`, I am using `C# 9.0`.

I have tried using `.ForceColor` as a way to change the color but as you can see, i am trying to accomplish a similar thing as the one in the example.

Comment: `Label1.ForeColor = Label2.ForeColor;` doesnt' work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, I suggest put labels in a container, And don't put anything except labels.
Then:

1. Do `for` loop, and `length = ContainerPanel.Controls.Count - 1`, with condition `i = ContainerPanel.Controls.Count`
2. Cast `Control[i]` to `labelFirst`
3. Cast `Control[i + 1]` to `labelSecond`
4. `labelFirst.ForeColor = labelSecond.ForeColor`

In this example, Container is: `ContainerPanel`

```
for (int i = 0; i < ContainerPanel.Controls.Count - 1; i++)
{
    // This is a simple way without variables
    (Label(ContainerPanel.Controls[i])).ForeColor = (Label(ContainerPanel.Controls[i + 1]));
}
```

**Note:** last Label You should change its `ForeColor`, Or it will not be changed.

#### Q&A

**Q:** Why `length = ContainerPanel.Controls.Count - 1`??

**A:** Because we should get Cast `Control[i + 1]` to `labelSecond`, And we can't, except if the length is less than controls count by one